Strategies to improve battery life in a location-based app? - Google Maps API error
I'm developing an Android app that uses Google Maps API to display user location and nearby points of interest. However, I'm noticing significant battery drain, especially when the app is running in the background.
Here's an example of how I'm requesting location updates:
    // Requesting location updates every 10 seconds
    LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
    request.setInterval(10000);
    request.setFastestInterval(5000);

    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, locationCallback, null);

    private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            // Update map with new location
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatLng(), 15));
        }
    };


This code snippet seems to be updating the user location quite frequently, potentially leading to excessive battery drain. I've tried increasing the update interval, but the app still drains battery quickly.
Here's an error message I sometimes encounter in the logcat:
    E/GoogleLocationManager: Failed to start location listener: 1

I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize location updates and reduce battery consumption in my app while still maintaining a reasonable level of location accuracy.

You may find this link helpful. Also make sure to call mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false); in onStop of activity.
